# how to bind large data to dropdown list in win8 store app

Tags: windows-store-apps

Is there a way to disable scrolling in a GridView in a Windows Store App? I have a GridView I want to disable the scroll of, such that when someone tries to scroll, the event should be ignored. I have tried adding an onTouch event, but onItemClick still fires. Is there a way to disable the scroll without triggering the onItemClick event?

Comment: First: are you using C#/Xaml? WinJS? C++? You're using camelCasing and referencing onTouch, which is not a GridView event, but GridView itself is not in WinJS. Second: Assuming you're using C#/Xaml, Have you tried setting `IsItemClickEnabled=False`? That should disable all item clicks for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this Attached property in the GridView to disable Vertical scrolling.

```
ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Disabled"
```